# Get list of ALM project AND domains names in VBScript (QC11 OTA)

Tags: vbscript, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am trying to list QC11 project and domain name in combo box on form load() but I am getting error object required,code I am using:

```
Dim tdc As New TDAPIOLELib.TDConnection
Dim projectList As Customization
Dim Project As Customization
Dim Domain As Customization
Set tdc = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
tdc.InitConnectionEx "https://xyz/omu"
For Each Domain In TheTDConnection.DomainsList
    Set projectList = tdc.GetAllVisibleProjectDescriptors
    For Each Project In projectList
        ComboBox1.AddItem (Project.Name)
        ComboBox2.AddItem (Project.DomainName)
    Next Project
Next Domain
```

Comment: Which statement is generating the "object required" error?

Comment: You have almost completely changed your code. Your original question was nothing to do with IXMLDOMNodeList and related to getting domains & projects from the ALM API. If that is solved then you should ask a different question for your file parsing needs.

Comment: ...and using a different API now too! (was OTA API, now the SiteAdmin API)

Comment: no issue didnot get resolved so i am trying to modify the code to get the solution

Comment: I have added a tested working solution that cycles through the domains/project that your user has access to.

Comment: I see where you're going with the SA and the XML parsing, but that really is almost a totally different questions to the original, not to mention things have apparently now morphed from VBScript to a VB application.

Comment: I'm obviously a masochist. Edit 2 in my answer will parse the XML from sa.GetAllDomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's really the code you are using, then for a start this line is probably generating an error:

```
For Each Domain In TheTDConnection.DomainsList
```

Based on the rest of your code "TheTDConnection" should be "tdc":

```
For Each Domain In tdc.DomainsList
```

Oh, and to be doing this you should almost certainly be logged in first by calling *tdc.Login...* rather than just connected to the server.

On a related note, the *DomainsList* property is deprecated. I think you can just loop through the List of ProjectDescriptor objects returned by *GetAllVisibleProjectDescriptors* since that covers all projects under all domains that the current logged on user has access to.

**Edit:** this is a complete solution based on the original question. Here's working tested code that will cycle through the domains/projects that the provided user has access to. This assumes you have the QC/ALM Connectivity add-in installed (required).

If you are running this piece of VBScript on a 64 bit machine you need to run it using the 32bit version of wscript.exe: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe "c:\somewhere\myscript.vbs"`

```
msgbox "Creating connection object"
Dim tdc
Set tdc = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
msgbox "Connecting to QC/ALM"
tdc.InitConnectionEx "http://<yourServer>/qcbin/"
msgbox "Logging in"
tdc.Login "<username>", "<password>"
Dim projDesc
msgbox "Getting project descriptors"
Set projectDescriptors = tdc.GetAllVisibleProjectDescriptors
For Each desc In projectDescriptors
    msgbox desc.DomainName & "\" & desc.Name
Next
msgbox "Logging out"
tdc.Logout
msgbox "Disconnecting"
tdc.Disconnect
msgbox "Releasing connection"
tdc.ReleaseConnection
```

**Edit 2:**

If you want to parse the resulting XML from sa.GetAllDomains into a list of ALL domain\project items on the server you can do this (This is VBScript since the original question & tag still mention it, and has been tested):

```
Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
objDoc.Load "C:\yourXmlFile.xml"
Set objRoot = objDoc.documentElement

For Each domain in objRoot.selectNodes("TDXItem")
  For Each project in domain.selectNodes("PROJECTS_LIST/TDXItem")
    msgbox domain.selectSingleNode("DOMAIN_NAME").text & "\" & project.selectSingleNode("PROJECT_NAME").text
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Looking at the OP's code, they are not doing anything with the Domain object anyway, at least not in the posted snippet.

Comment: @user635545 Have you tried adding code to login first? Can you be more specific and tell us which line is currently causing the error?

Comment: Dim MyNodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Line itself causing the error

Comment: @Xiaofu: Could you please share a link where I can find a complete documentation on TDAPIOLELib.TDConnection? Thanks.